# Appium swipe gesture not working in a list in Android

Tags: android, appium

I am working on a real android device through mac , executing java commands from eclipse, everything works great except the swipe command, here is my code :

```
wd = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//enter user name (works)
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys(username);

//enter password(works)
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys(password);

//click login(works)
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]")).click();

//try to swipe a list (does not work)
wd.swipe(300, 300, 1, 300, 1500);
```

Comment: two things : **1.** make sure the `(x,y)` coordinates specified exists on the screen and **2.** reduce the duration to perform the `swipe`
Try this `wd.swipe(300, 300, 1, 300, 10);`

Comment: I took the dimensions from enabling the "show pointer location" in the developer options, so am sure they exist tried to reduce the duration didn't work.

Comment: i hope you have also read the 3rd point in the answer posted by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone facing a similar problem here is how it got solved,
I simply added a random assertion on the list , since I discovered that  the swipe function gets executed instantly unlike the other functions which waits for the previous task to finish before executing (probably a bug).

tldr: I added this before the swipe

```
String firstName =  wd.findElementByName("aerobics 101").getText();
Assert.assertEquals("aerobics 101", firstName);
```

Example:

**[1]** `wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys(password);`

> The system waits 30 seconds between **[1]** and **[2]**

**[2]**
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.ScrollView[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]")).click();

> No wait between **[2]** and **[3]** !!!!!!!

**[3]**

```
wd.swipe(300, 300, 1, 300, 1500);
```

Comment: what do you mean instantly after the previous command ? could you share more details and stats to it

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the comment, two things :

**1.** Make sure the `(x,y) coordinates` specified by you actually exists on the screen.

**2.** Reduce the duration to perform the swipe, try this

```
wd.swipe(300, 300, 1, 300, 10);
```

**3.** One crucial thing, definition of the method you are trying to use :

```
public void swipe(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int duration) {
    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(this);

    // appium converts press-wait-moveto-release to a swipe action
    touchAction.press(startx, starty).waitAction(duration)
            .moveTo(endx, endy).release();

    touchAction.perform();
}
```

Looking at this and your inputs : 
`startx = 300 ; starty = 300 ; endx = 1 ; endy = 300` you seem to be doing a **`swipe left at height 300`**, which we shall *assume* is what you are *expecting* and if not, the coordinates need to be changed.

Comment: The problem was that swipe action was executed instantly after the commend before it , I saw it when I enabled the "Show touches" in developer options . My touch coordinates are taken from "Show pointer location" in developer options .

Answer (score 0):

Find 2 corner(left and the right one) elements by name on the current screen and use this method to swipe:

```
public void swipeScreen(String name, String move) {
    WebElement longPress = driver.findElementByName(name);
    WebElement moveTo = driver.findElementByName(move);
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(longPress, 20000).moveTo(moveTo).release();
    action.perform();
}
```

Comment: this seems like a `drag` rather than a `swipe`, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: if you just find 2 elements on screen from each corner, this would swipe the screen.

Comment: swipe uses `press` not `longPress`, you can refer to the definition from the java-client, i have shared the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

First I would take the dimensions of the screen:

Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();

After you have this, take the x and y values by using the dimension instance.
        int middleX = dimension.getWidth() / 2;
        int middleY = dimension.getHeight() / 2;
        int quarterY = dimension.getHeight() / 4;
        driver.swipe(middleX, middleY, middleX, quarterY , duration );

In the duration I would use 800 or 1000 which is slow enough.

Comment: I took the dimensions from enabling the "show pointer location" in the developer options